# Retrieving Data From AdMob and Integrating it into an App

Tags: java, android, parsing, admob

I am creating an app where people can watch ads to get rewards. In order to display how much money they earned, I want to be able to query the amount of money earned by a specific interstitial ad in a given day.

Is this possible using AdMob? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

You can run reports for your new AdMob account using the AdSense Management API. https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/libraries